# Creating a css background pattern of little squares and controlling the opacity

Tags: css

How to replicate this image in css to serve as a background for text?

[image]

(It's kind of hard to see but they're individual squares, not dots.)

The squares should be transparent as well.

Also it is possible to code it to control the opacity of each horizontal line of squares in css?

Comment: Something like this - https://jsfiddle.net/s9ovyer0/ ?

Comment: @pol seems like it is not possible to create pure individual squares with linear-gradient?

Comment: @Fortytwo Yes it is possible, and it can be done a lot simpler. I will post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1.** Here's one way of doing it using pseudo-elements, adjust the values to your liking:

Snippet:

```css
html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; }

.checkered-bg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  color: white;
}

.checkered-bg::before, .checkered-bg::after {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: -1;
}

.checkered-bg::before {
  background-image:
    linear-gradient(black 50%, transparent 50%),
    linear-gradient(to right, grey 50%, black 50%);
  background-size: 20px 20px;
}

.checkered-bg::after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(black, transparent);
}
```

```html
<div class="checkered-bg">CONTENT</div>
```

View on [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jvcgds5r/).

**2.** Another way to make the squares and have the area around them transparent. But in order to get the top rows more translucent you will need a solid color:

```css
html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; }

.checkered-bg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  color: black;
}

.checkered-bg::before, .checkered-bg::after {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: -1;
}

.checkered-bg::before {
  background-image:
    linear-gradient(45deg, #808080 25%, transparent 25%), 
    linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 75%, #808080 75%);
  
  background-size:20px 20px;
  background-position:0 0, -10px -10px;
}


.checkered-bg::after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(#808080, transparent);
}
```

```html
<div class="checkered-bg">CONTENT</div>
```

View on [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ot1hsfx6/)

Option #2 smaller squares - [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ot1hsfx6/5/)

Comment: So it needs a solid background color in order to see the squares? Can I make background transparent and only see the squares?

Comment: @Fortytwo Sure, you can get the squares to be individual and the space around them to be transparent. But in order to make the top rows translucent you will need a linear-gradient starting from one color and ending transparent. I've added this second way in the answer.

Comment: On the second way, how can I decrease the squares sizes? I want to fit it in a 180px / 60px box, but I can't change the little square sizes without breaking the squares in background-size.

Comment: @Fortytwo I suggest using even values for the `background-size` to make them look like squares, otherwise they will be rectangles. I've added this in the answer.